# Difference between concat function and resource id function in Azure ARM Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two and which one should be used in the resource section in an Azure ARM JSON template

```json
"dependsOn": [
      [concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
```

```json
"dependsOn": [
      [resourceid('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
```

Answer (score 1):

resourceId is just a convenient way to generate resourceId, not the "fake" one, because the example you are showing would only work in the dependsOn property, if you attempt to use your concat example with any function\resource property that expects a resourceId it will fail.

Basically, dependsOn allows a couple of shortcuts when it parses the input, so you can do something like this:

```
dependsOn: [
    "resourceName"
]
```

and if that name is unique - that is fine. but its not a real resourceId as you probably figured.

concat: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#concat
resourceId: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid

Answer (score 0):

The "concat" function:

- Combines multiple arrays into one array 
  or
- Combines multiple strings into single string

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#concat) for more details.

Whereas the "resourceId" function:

- It gives the unique identifier of the resource for which it is being called.
  see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid) for more details.

Now for your question that "which one should be used in the resource section in an Azure ARM JSON template".
Following, I have used in my ARM templates and it is working for me:

```
"availabilitySet": { "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('availabilitySetName'))]" }
        }
```